# CouchDB replicating to a different version

Tags: couchdb

I have a production CouchDB application that is running version 1.2.1, and I would like to replicate - but the version on the server I want to replicate to is on version  1.6.1.

Would this be safe ? Will I encounter version issues later on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be safe to replicate from old versions to new ones and there wouldn't be any issues which you'll accidentally fall later. However, in your case it also matters which CouchDB version will run a replication and is this one time operation or continuous one. Since CouchDB 1.3 replicator get improved a lot to be more reliable, fast and flexible in configuration in addition to various bugfixes which it eventually received. So, you better run replication on 1.6.1 server to pull the data from 1.2.1 one to ensure your self that you'll avoid any old issues and make it effectively.